# Azure Data Factory - File System to Oracle Cloud Storage

Tags: filesystems, azure-data-factory, cloud-storage

Is it possible to copy files from an on-prem File System to Oracle Cloud Storage. Note that we are not concerned with the data inside the files.

In simple terms it's as if copying files from one folder to another.
Here is what I have tried:

1. Created Self-Hosted Runtime for the file system (testing on my local machine)
2. Created Linked Service for File System
3. Linked Service for Oracle Cloud Storage (OCS)
4. Data Set of File System
5. Data set of Oracle (OCS)

However, I get error saying that my C:\ can not be resolved in step 2. when connection is tested.
and
In 5. it says not able to sink because it is not supported under OCS. At this point it seems like it is not possible to copy files into OCS?

I tried different configurations to see if OCS can be used as a drop container for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to make sure that the self-hosted integration runtime is installed and configured correctly on the machine where the on-premises file system is located and can connect to the file system without issues. Please make sure you meet all the requirements as called out in this public documentation: [Create and configure a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory)
Related helpful video by community volunteers: [ADF | Copy files from On-premises file system into blob](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCojSSEZ4LA)

Oracle Cloud Storage connector in ADF is only supported as source (to read data from Oracle Cloud storage) but not as sink (not to copy files/data).

To workaround, if Oracle cloud storage supports REST API to copy files, then you may explore [web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) in ADF. Else you will have to look for solutions outside of ADF.

Comment: Web activity can be used to copy files from on-prem to oracle cloud. However, files first need to be copied to a azure blob storage and then from there, files can be moved using Web activities (GET and PUT) to oracle cloud storage.